# How to paint graphics from multiple classes to a single panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

At the moment, I have two JPanel classes that draw images and shapes to a JFrame (I will have more in the future), I'm doing this to make things organised.

At first I tried to add each JPanel to the JFrame, but one JPanel would paint over the other.

Each class should be able to call other classes that may draw images to screen as well.

The problem I have is that I cannot get them to draw to the screen.

Should I use `paintComponent` or `paintAll`? And how should they be used?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: _but one JPanel would paint other the other_, fix this mistake.

Comment: _Each class should be able to call other classes_, are you using objects, or `static` methods? Add some code.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) It seems likely from the description that the classes should not be panels, but objects that know how to paint themselves to a `Graphics` instance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you are adding both panels to the same location in the `JFrame` probably in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. One solution is to use a `GridLayout` with 2 columns for the `JFrame` and add the 2 panels.

`paintComponent` is the correct method to override in your panels.

Follow the [custom painting trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to see how it should be used.